# why is the path for my img tag src attribute failing?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I've tried every possible relative path combination I can think of and I'm still getting a broken img icon on my page when I try to load it. The only thing that works is when I test an absolute path from a sample pic on the web.

The image i'm trying to load is in the exact same directory as the html page I want to load it to.

My file structure is as follows

```
                              src -> 
                                  pages -> 
                                         home-> 
                                                - home.html 

                                                - vectorstock_1623.jpg
```

**Home.html**

```
<img src="vectorstock_1623.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the image in the `src/assets` folder. You can create an `img` folder inside the `assets` folder so your image will be placed in:

`src/assets/img`

and then in the view use this path:

```
<img src="assets/img/vectorstock_1623.jpg">
```